# how to do xsl:include over https in saxon?

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm trying to run a transform directly from github. Saxon opens the initial xsl, but barfs on included xsls:

```
transform -xsl:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VladimirAlexiev/LODE/master/src/main/webapp/extraction.xsl -s:ebg-ontology.rdf -o:index.html
Error on line 35 column 43 of extraction.xsl:
  XTSE0165: I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VladimirAlexiev/LODE/master/src/main/webapp/swrl-module.xsl:
   unknown protocol: https
```

Question [Saxon error with XSLT import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236291) is slightly related but it uses java whereas I run from the command line. @michael-kay suggests there to add a base URL: I've added `xml:base="."` to no avail (and as you can see from the error message, the url of the module is correct).

What should I to do to enable Saxon to handle `https`? Running SaxonHE9-7-0-21N-setup.exe

Comment: I had a different error message when trying to use Saxon .NET and HTTPS content at https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/7108 and the suggestions made there to add a `Transform.exe.config` for Saxon that enables the `<add key="ikvm:https.protocols" value="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />` fixed that problem. Not sure whether the error message you get is caused by the same problem and resolvable the same way, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: Martin's case was slightly different because it used unparsed-text() rather than xsl:include. For unparsed-text() Saxon tries to open the URLConnection itself, but for xsl:include it leaves everything to the XML parser. You could experiment with setting an XmlResolver on the XsltCompiler and taking charge of the URI resolution yourself.